# Complex(?) Name Matching Regex for vBulletin

Tags: php, regex, match, vbulletin

I'm creating some custom BBcode for a forum. I'm trying to get the regular expression right, but it has been eluding me for weeks. Any expert advice is welcome.

Sample input (a very basic example):

```
[quote=Bob]I like Candace. She is nice.[/quote]

Ashley Ryan Thomas
```

Essentially, I want to encase any names (from a specified list) in [user][/user] BBcode... except, of course, those being quoted, because doing that causes some terrible parsing errors.

The desired output:

```
[quote=Bob]I like [user]Candace[/user]. She is nice.[/quote]

[user]Ashley[/user] [user]Ryan[/user] [user]Thomas[/user]
```

My current code:

```
 $searchArray = array(
 '/(?i)([^=]|\b|\s|\/|\r|\n|\t|^)(Ashley|Bob|Candace|Ryan|Thomas)(\s|\r|\n|\t|,|\.(\b|\s|\.|$)|;|:|\'|"|-|!|\?|\)|\/|\[|$)/'
 );

 $replaceArray = array(
   "\\1[user]\\2[/user]\\3"
 );

 $text = preg_replace($searchArray, $replaceArray, $input);
```

What it currently produces:

```
 [quote=Bob]I like [user]Candace[/user]. She is nice.[/quote]

 [user]Ashley[/user] Ryan [user]Thomas[/user]
```

Notice that Ryan isn't encapsulated by [user] tags. Also note that much of the additional regex matching characters were added on an as-needed basis as they cropped up on the forums, so removing them will simply make it fail to match in other situations (i.e. a no-no). Unless, of course, you spot a glaring error in the regex itself, in which case please do point it out.

Really, though, any assistance would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

Comment: http://codepad.org/01KroH93

Your code seems to work. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simply that you are matching delimiters `(\s|\r|...)` at both ends of the searched names. The poor `Ashley` and `Ryan` share a single space character in your test string. But the regex can only match it once - as left or right border.

The solution here is to use assertions. Enclose the left list in `(?<= )` and the right in `(?= )` so they become:

```
 (?<=[^=]|\b|\s|\/|^)
 (?=\s|,|\.(\b|\s|\.|$)|;|:|\'|"|-|!|\?|\)|\/|\[|$)
```

Btw, `\s` already contains `\r|\n|\t` so you can probably remove that.

Comment: Precisely what I needed. I never even knew lookahead assertions existed. Thanks for the schooling!

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't really need to match the spaces on either side (just make sure they're there, right?) try replacing your search expression with this:

```
$searchArray = array(
  '/\b(Ashley|Bob|Candace|Ryan|Thomas)\b/i'
);

$replaceArray = array(
 '[user]$1[/user]'
);

$text = preg_replace($searchArray, $replaceArray, $input);
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. This is actually how my regex started off, but after weeks of viewing forum users' behavior, I unfortunately concluded that I need all the extraneous character matching I've tossed in over time.

Comment: the \b anchor matches the boundary between a word-class character (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and _) and any other character, so assuming that all of your usernames at the very least start and end with one of these characters, it accomplishes the same end result as your extra character matching.

Comment: Mostly true, but as I said, this is for a forum. I need those extra character matches for situations where people write things like:

Ashely/Bob/Candace

or

Bob...Ryan...

Comment: @daveycroqet as this jsfiddle ([link](http://jsfiddle.net/DPzcv/)) shows, both of those conditions are matched by the regular expression that I provided, and without the overhead of lookahead/behinds. In fact, any condition matched by the expression in the accepted answer will be matched by this one, as well as other punctuation/characters that you may have forgotten, and this one will match them more efficiently

Comment: It unfortunately also matches Bob in [quote=Bob], which I specified that I did not want to occur. As I said, I began with that exact regex, but over time needed a more complex solution as I observed forum-goers in their day-to-day interactions. I would much rather have an elegant, simple solution like yours, but ultimately I gave up on it.