# Complex Regex Matching with Capture Groups

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm trying to match some weather in a weather report (METAR format, if that helps).  The text to match can consist of the following:

"RA" or "SN" or "TS" followed by "B" and two or four digits, or "E" and two or four digits, or both, or multiple "B" and "E" groups (e.g. B05E20B45), resulting in something like  "RAB05E20B45".  This translates to "rain began at 05 past the hour, ended at 20 past, and began again at 45 past".  In addition, there can be multiple constructions like this in the same string (e.g. "RAB05E20SNB25E55" = "rain began at 05, ended at 20, then snow began at 25 and ended at 55").

Here are some example inputs and the output I'd like to get:

```
RAB05                     RAB05
RAB05E15                  RAB05E15
RAB05E15SNB25             RAB05E15     SNB05
RAB05E15SNB25E55          RAB05E15     SNB25E55
TSE01RAB05E15SNB25        TSE01        RAB05E15     SNB25
TSB01E55RAE15SNB25E55     TSB01E55     RAE15        SNB25E55
```

I was fairly cocky in thinking that the following would do it...

```
((?:RA|SN|TS)(?:(?:B|E)(?:\d{2}|\d{4}))+)+
```

...but since I'm here crying about it it obviously doesn't.

Here is my test code (VB 2013):

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Form1
    Dim sItem As String = "TSB05E10RAB15"
    Dim sPattern As String = "((?:RA|SN|TS)(?:(?:B|E)(?:\d{2}|\d{4}))+)+"

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If Regex.Match(sItem, sPattern).Success Then
            Dim rxMatches As GroupCollection = Regex.Match(sItem, sPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups

            '0th item is the entire match (e.g. TSB05E10RAB15)
            'Succeeding elements are capture groups
            For i = 1 To rxMatches.Count - 1
                MessageBox.Show("Match #" & i & " = " & rxMatches(i).Value)
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

The results I expect are "TSB05E10" and "RAB15", but all I'm getting is "RAB15".

I searched the following, among others, to no avail:

- [Complex(?) Name Matching Regex for vBulletin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772025/complex-name-matching-regex-for-vbulletin)
- [Complex regex to split up a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428889/complex-regex-to-split-up-a-string)
- [Complex regex to split up a string - Part 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756172/complex-regex-to-split-up-a-string-part-2)

If someone would be so kind as to show me the error(s) of my ways...

EDIT:

Thanks to everyone that helped. Here is the working solution:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Form1
    Dim sItem As String = "TSB05E10SHRAB10E15SNB25E35B45E55"
    Dim sPattern As String = "(?:(?:SH)?(?:RA|SN)|TS)(?:(?:B|E)(?:\d{2}|\d{4}))+"
    Dim rx As New Regex(sPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim matches As MatchCollection = rx.Matches(sItem)

        Label1.Text = "Input: " & sItem

        For Each match As Match In matches
            Dim groups As GroupCollection = match.Groups

            ListBox1.Items.Add(groups.Item(0).Value)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Your regex [matches all your examples](http://rubular.com/r/ICsUjHuyQl). What's the problem?

Comment: Looks good to me as well. [See it working here](http://regexr.com?37v44)

I checked the global checkbox and used the following: _((RA|SN|TS)((B|E)\d{2,4})+)_

Comment: As the guys said that it is working, can you provide a sample that it should work but it isn't?!

Comment: I believe the first column is the data, the remaining columns are the sections to parse out using the regex.

Comment: Is there a reason that splitting this by whitespace and then parsing individual elements won't work? I imagine that would make your code much cleaner (easier to understand and maintain). Regular expressions are cool, but sometimes they're a pain in the rear and are better avoided.

Comment: While a METAR is delimited by whitespace, the precipitation begin/end item is just one string containing the begin/end times of all precipitation (e.g. TSB05E10RAB20E35, which has both a thunder storm and rain start/stop times)

Comment: When you write a regex like `(foo)+`, it only captures one substring (the last one), even with a string like `foofoo`. If you know in advance how many to expect, you could tailor the regex to capture them all; but you don't. If you want all of them, you need to say to the regex engine "find me all matches of this regex" instead of "find me a match". You should remove `+` from the end of the regex, and change the line `Dim rxMatches As GroupCollection = ...` to something else. I don't know quite what because I don't know the language, but `rxMatches` should be an array of `GroupCollection`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are those real METAR's?  I would have thought you'd need to have a beginning and end time for each precipitation type.  In addition, if the precipitation is showery, there may be an SH prior to the precipitation type.  Also, you specified your digit quantifier as {2,4} which means 2, 3 or 4; and it really should be 2 or 4 as you stated.

In any event, for your requirements (and adding in the optional SH and using non-capturing groups to reduce overhead) try:

```
(?:SH)?(?:RA|SN|TS)(?:(?:B|E)(?:\d{2}|\d{4}))+
```

**Edit:**  to shorten the regex.

With regard to your regex, your problem was the anchors, and the fact that you were repeating the precipitation types, when you want to parse out the different precipitation types separately

**Edit:** I'm not sure about VB 2013, but in other VB variations, you need to set the Global property of the Regex object to True.

---

Explanation of RegEx:

- `(?:SH)?` - optional non-capturing group matching "SH"
- `(?:RA|SN|TS)` - non-capturing group matching "RA" or "SN" or "TS"
- `(?:(?:B|E)(?:\d{2}|\d{4}))+` - "B" or "E" followed by 2 or 4 digits (this may be repeated one or more times)

Non-capturing group just means that the stuff in the parenthesis is used as a part of the match but the group is not "saved" to be accessed later (which is how regular parenthesis would work).

If you break it all down it's really quite simple to understand if you take the time.

Comment: This regex reminds me of why I don't usually look to them as my first solution... I'm sure it's correct (probably), but reading it is like reading assembly.

Comment: I used to program in assembly.  Maybe that's why I find the most difficult part of the regex is understanding the problem :-)

Comment: It is "real" sample data, in that it is valid, but no, I did not copy it out of a real METAR. There does not have to be both a beginning and an ending time (in case it is on-going, or started in a previous observation). Yes, you're right about the showers, but I was leaving that out for the moment to get the basics working without an added level of complexity.

Comment: @Brian And did my regex work the way you require?  Was my assumption correct that it is column 1 that is your data, and the other columns are what needs to be returned?

Comment: @Brian  I just updated my Answer to indicate that you may need to set the Global property to True.  Then each will be returned as a separate Match. No need for capturing groups and submatches.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld: Yes, the first column is the data, and the succeeding columns are what I'd like to get back via capture groups. Your pattern (using my sample code above) matches the first precipitation element (TSB05E10). I'm not getting the second element in my results (RAB15). Since there can be one each of RA, SN, and TS in a single string, shouldn't the entire (showers & non-capture omitted for brevity) pattern be wrapped in parenthesis, followed by a plus, as in  
`((RA|SN|TS)(\d{2}|(\d{4})+)+`  Isn't the plus sign greedy, in that it has to find at least one, but will find more than one?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld: I changed your pattern to `((?:RA|SN|TS)(?:(?:B|E)(?:\d{2}|\d{4}))+)+` to account for showers not being applicable to TS. See my edited original question for the working solution. (Do you have some experience working with METAR?) Thanks for the help!

Comment: Splitting of SH like that is not necessary, unless you are trying to validate the METAR and, if you were trying to do that, the regex would need to be a lot more complex.  Since SHTS should never occur in well formed METARs, the fact that the regex accepts it is irrelevant. (The regex will also accept other malformed pptn events). And yes, I review METARS frequently.

Comment: Yes, I didn't think that change through. I'm working with "official" METAR data, so there is no need to check it for validity. How is it that you review METARs often? I work with them all the time as an air traffic controller. Programming things to make my job better and/or easier I do for fun (and because some of the software we use is so irritatingly done that I can't help myself).